# How to stop htop controlling terminal's mouse?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, gnome-terminal, htop

When you running htop (with Gnome-Terminal + Ubuntu 14.04), and left-clicking a process on the terminal window, htop will move cursor into that process.  I prefer to disable it, but I didn't find in manuals.

PS: I know I can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select words, but I just want to disable it totally.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest LTS, Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy), htop 3.0.5-7build2 supports `--no-mouse` to disable this behavior:

- https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/htop.1.html

Also in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187716 the author provides an approach to disable it entirely (but I haven't tested it) by modifying terminfo.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that for some (old?) versions of htop, the `-M` or `--no-mouse` option only disables mouse control so that clicking in terminal does not select a line, but the user still cannot select text without pressing `Shift` or `fn`(on macOS)